# Eclipse JDT IJavaProject get root file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the below code fragment which returns the relevant `IJavaProject` from a `CompiliationUnit`:

```
IJavaProject project = compilationUnit.getJavaProject();
```

I need to find a file in the root of the project, but I can't figure out how to locate it. If I loop on `project.getAllPackageFragmentRoots()` I can see the src folder,the package below the src folder, and the standard JRE classes, but not my root file.

How can I load the a file under the root folder? (Preferably into a `File` object)

Comment: what do you mean with root file? folder where is project located?

Comment: I mean a file under the project root folder

Comment: try getResource() on project, should return Folder or wrapped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my solution:

```
    IJavaProject project = compilationUnit.getJavaProject();

    IProject p = project.getProject();
    IFile rm = p.getFile("file.xml");
```

Simple really.